# Storing a car on wood blocks in storage unit

Tags: tires

I'm going to Air Force Field Training this summer, which means that I will have to leave my car unattended (in Prescott, AZ) for a month.  This is a problem for a few reasons:

- I have Goodyear MT/R tires which are made of Kevlar.  If the tires rest on hot pavement for too long they will develop flat spots.
- It's a soft top Jeep that's been broken into before
- I would like to keep the paint out of the sun, since I can't be washing and waxing it.
- I don't have a garage to use, and a fabric cover would cost more than 1 months rent at a storage unit.

My main question is if it's OK to jack up the car, and rest the axles (close to the wheel) on wooden blocks for a month.  I would like to keep the MT/R tires off the ground (for the reason mentioned above), and I was wondering if that's the best way to do so.

Any other advice on storing a vehicle in the dessert is also appreciated.

Comment: @DucatiKiller, I am planning on putting it inside a storage unit.

Answer (score 4):

I would jack the vehicle up and use jack stands instead of blocks. Even the cheapest jack stands would be safer than stacked wood. If it is only sitting for a month, the jack stands on the axle tubes will be fine. If it will be in long term storage then I would put the jack stands on the frame. By supporting it by the frame the suspension will be unloaded also.

Comment: There's two problems with this.  1: I'm a college student, and my Jack stands are in my home town, but I won't be able to get them before I leave for FT, and I don't want to buy more. 2: my jack stands aren't high enough to rest the Jeep on without getting the tires off the ground.  What about using cinder blocks under the frame?

Comment: They would work but  don't  crawl under it . Make sure you place them with the open side facing up.

Answer (score 0):

Does anyone you know have a set of jack stands you can borrow? May be a better option than cinderblocks or wood. One other consideration is to put fuel stabilizer in the tank, then fill it all the way up. This will help keep the fuel from getting stale while sitting for the month. Also, disconnect the battery so it doesn't get the slow drain whammy put on it from the vehicle system. This and putting it on blocks should alleviate any issues you might have when you get back to your go buggy.