# Storing manual transmission diesel car for 4-6 months, what 'else'

Tags: diesel, long-term-storage

I don't have anybody who can run the car in between, or just start etc., so here is what I plan to do

1. Put lot of silica gel inside
2. Cover the car
3. Remove battery
4. Top up fuel (Diesel car)
5. Pump up the tires to 40 psi (32 is recommended)

What else should I do?
Will tires develop flat spots? If so, should I raise the car?

On coming back, can I start, and drive to the workshop for an oil change and its all good, or some more things need to be done?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Storing a car on wood blocks in storage unit](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/16259/storing-a-car-on-wood-blocks-in-storage-unit)

Comment: I'm inclined to leave it open, the possible duplicate is mostly about tires. This is a broader question.

Comment: Is the vehicle going to be stored indoors or outdoors?

Answer (score 1):

If it is viable (even ground) I would suggest you to not engage the parking brake, chances are that the brakes will rust stuck. Just put in the first or reverse so that the car cannot move. I would also advise you to use some fuel stabilizer to prevent the growth of algae/bacteria.

Since a car battery needs also some shaking/vibration to counter acid stratification it could be possible that you need a new battery after returning.

Comment: I've never heard of a car battery needing movement to keep it healthy -- lots of people use various grades of stationary lead acid batteries for solar systems, and plenty of people store RV's, cars and boats for months over the winter without replacing their batteries each year.

Comment: @Johnny http://www.upsbatterycenter.com/blog/understanding-acid-stratification-lead-acid-batteries/